# PEX/Intellitest: is possible to deal with Dictionary as symbolic input?

Tags: c#, pex, intellitest

intellitest documentation says

> IntelliTest's constraint solver can deal with values of all types that **may appear in .NET programs**.

But seems not works symbolically with Dictionary.